# Intervention \ Image \ Exception \ NotWritableException Can't write image data to path

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, intervention

I am trying to upload pictures in my site and i have intervention image installed. Here is my code

```
 $image = $request->file('image');
    $imagename = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $imagename = time().'.'.$imagename;

    $destinationPath = URL::to('public/images/categories');
    $img = Image::make($image->getRealPath());

    $img->resize(100, 100, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
    })->save($destinationPath.'/'.$imagename);

    $destinationPath = URL::to('public/images/categories');
```

i get the following error.

```
Intervention \ Image \ Exception \ NotWritableException
Can't write image data to path (http://www.mama- 
put.com/public/images/categories/1527334545.jpg)
```

What am i doing wrong? It works well on local machine but not on the server

Comment: check permission for that image folder

Comment: @arun yeah i have and this is what i got. drwxrwxrwx 3 root www-data

Comment: is the `category` folder exist with permission `drwxrwxrwx `?

Comment: Yes @arun it does. drwxrwxrwx 2 root www-data 4096

Answer (score 0):

you must use the path on your server, not the URL.

```
$destinationPath = storage_path('public/images/categories');
$img = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
```